# In Python, how to insert PNG image converted from html WEBP to excel without saving image and appending images in local PC folder?

Tags: python-imaging-library, png, openpyxl, jpeg, webp

My target is scraping html data including sorted information and WEBP images and saving to Excel sheet.
WEBP format images cannot be inserted to Excel sheet directly. The only way is converting WEBP to PNG or JPG first. But with bulk images converting image, saving to PC hard disk and inserting saved PNG from local PC to Excel takes time to process.
Is any way that WEBP image is converted to PNG and inserted to excel directly?

**# Partial codes below**

```
url = "https://down-aka-tw.img.susercontent.com/tw-11134207-7qul7-lilu03jxchpw3d_tn.webp" 

response = requests.get(url)

img_data = response.content

img_png = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(url).content)).convert("RGB") #from PIL import Image as pImage

img_png.save("C:\\temp\\image.png")

img = oImage('C:\\temp\\image.png')  #from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as oImage

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# insert images
ws.add_image(img, 'A1')

wb.save("C:\\temp\\export.xlsx")
wb.close()
```

I did try to insert converted Binary img_png to Excel sheet but it failed. However downloading URL WEBP, converting to PNG then save to PC is workable.
img_png can be print() or show(). If img_png inserted to Excel, it cannot be accepted. So I save PNG to image.png file and open the image using openpyxl(oImage). img can be inserted to Excel.

Is there any way that WEBP image is converted to PNG and inserted to excel directly without saving locally before inserting to Excel.

Comment: openpyxl will happily process WEBP images but not all programs can render them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save as a PNG BytesIO and open as `openpyxl.drawing.image` before inserting into the sheet.

```
from io import BytesIO
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as oImage
import requests
from PIL import Image as pImage
from openpyxl import Workbook


### Get image from URL
url = "https://down-aka-tw.img.susercontent.com/tw-11134207-7qul7-lilu03jxchpw3d_tn.webp"
response = requests.get(url)

img_data = response.content
img_png = pImage.open(BytesIO(requests.get(url).content)).convert("RGB") #from PIL import Image as pImage

# img_png.save("C:\\temp\\image.png")
# img = oImage('C:\\temp\\image.png')  #from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as oImage

### Create Workbook and Sheet
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

### Convert image to PNG for Openpyxl use
img_stream = BytesIO()
img_png.save(img_stream, format='PNG')
img_openpyxl = oImage(img_stream)

### Add Image to sheet
ws.add_image(img_openpyxl, 'A1')

wb.save("C:\\temp\\export.xlsx")
# wb.close()  #  This line does nothing in your code.
```

Comment: I think it's best to put anything network-based in it's own function so that it can, potentially at least, run in parallel.

Comment: Follow the codes, they work great but I find a question. "img_data = response.content" This one is useless. The processing is still working after hiding ima_data. is it correct?

Comment: That's fine if it works. My angle was more getting your img_png to something you could insert into Excel without saving it first.

Comment: One more question, I did spend long time to figure out problems and look for solution. But the soonest idea is asking help in stack overflow. Any suggestion to seek solution by myself? The webp images are converted to png which are displayable and can be saved. How do I know the process to create a new BytesIO object for storing image data in memory?

Comment: @陳韋仲 It all comes from experience and what areas of programming you are interested in. If your job is not full time Python Programming then its unlikely you will 'know' every possible module available and even then probably not. Something like this is not covered in the module tutorials and this is the reason for a site like SO, it's a database of questions that everyone can use. If you knew exactly what is needed you may have been able to search specifically enough to find exactly what you want there are other similar questions/answers that would have pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: However sometimes it difficult to express what is needed if you haven't worked on the issue before so again hopefully you can explain your requirement well enough that another person can understand and point you to where to find the answer or propose a method to do what you need. Now that you have the basic modules you can read up on these to learn more on how they work and how they were applied in this answer